# Android: Test Ads not loaded

Tags: android, admob

i am trying to add TestAds to my current activity but the activity is not showing any Ad . i have also add internet permission to Android Manifest.xml.
I get error code : 0
#

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("id")        
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: How long you have created the admob account? Which Banner are you using? Are you using real device or emulator(better use emulator)

Comment: about 1 month but i need to show testads

Comment: Also are you using correct testDevice id??

Comment: i will using real phone

Comment: What id are you using? Real one or you just add "id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use your real device id as test device id, "id" not represent anything. In this case you should see normal ads(if your app and ad id is correct)

it should something like this .addTestDevice("FB9F1C3D53382E1666489F5407301E91") that you can find in logcat

if you can not obtain your id from logcat, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" you can use this ad id.

Also be sure you added adview and adview has attribute value "wrap content" attribute both for height and width

Comment: how to get device id

Comment: First loaf your add without a test device id parameter. Then check logcat for ads you. Try ro capture a line that indicates to add this device as test device " DEVICE ID " then add this line to the code

Comment: yeah i got it and it showing test ads now i want to show real ads what i do thank you!!

Comment: When you publish your app you will see real ads. If you test it in another device that not added as Test Device, you will also see real ads. 

Just be sure, you are using your real Banner Ad Unit id.

Comment: my app is not published on playstore how i test if real ads working?

Comment: if you see test ads with your real banner ad unit id. it means it works